# Testing method for swapping two variables with JUnit

Tags: java, testing, methods, junit, swap

I've got a class with a method for swapping two variables. It returns nothing.

```
public void swap(int a, int b) {
    a ^= b;
    b = a ^ b;
    a = a ^ b;
}
```

How can I test it with JUnit? It even doesn't cause any side-effects.

Comment: And what should this method do (maybe off-topic question)?

Comment: If it returns nothing and has no side effect, there is nothing to test...

Answer (score 2):

**There is nothing to test.**

The method *does nothing*: it returns `void` and it has no side effect (no mutation, ...).

Answer (score 1):

Your method doesn't just return nothing, it *does* nothing, at least in terms of observable side effects.

If you want to make your method in any way useful, you need to change it to do something you can observe. For instance, you can change it to accept single-element array arguments:

```
public void swap(int[] a, int[] b) {
    a[0] ^= b[0];
    b[0] = a[0] ^ b[0];
    a[0] = a[0] ^ b[0];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The function written by you does not perform any swap for the values of 'a' and 'b' because in java the values of primitive types are pass-by-value.

```
public void swap(int a, int b) {
    a ^= b;
    b = a ^ b;
    a = a ^ b;
}
```

The function suggested by putting values into arrays of length 1 and then performing the swap operation will work as arrays are pass-by-reference.

```
public void swap(int[] a, int[] b) {
    a[0] ^= b[0];
    b[0] = a[0] ^ b[0];
    a[0] = a[0] ^ b[0];
}
```

However, the function will fail in case when both arrays a and b refer to the same array. The above function will make the zeroth element as zero for the array that is passed as the argument for both the arguments. So we need to change the above function in the following manner:-

```
public void swap(int[] a, int[] b) {
    if (a == b) { //do not swap 
        return;
    }

    if (a ==null) {
        return;
    }

    if (b ==null) {
        return;
    }

    a[0] ^= b[0];
    b[0] = a[0] ^ b[0];
    a[0] = a[0] ^ b[0];
}
```

I will suggest some Junit test cases for the above code. You could use assertEquals() from JUnit package to test the values in a[1] and b[1] if they were swapped.

```
//both a[0] and b[0] are different values
int[] a = {4};
int[] b = {5};

int copy_a = a[0];
int copy_b = b[0];

swap(a, b);

assertEquals("copy_a should be b[0]", copy_a, b[0]);
assertEquals("copy_b should be a[0]", copy_b, a[0]);

//both a[0] and b[0] are same values
a[0] = 4;
b[0] = 4;

copy_a = a[0];
copy_b = b[0];

swap(a, b);

assertEquals("copy_a should be copy_b", copy_a == copy_b, a[0] == b[0]);

//case when you pass same array as both arguments.

a[0] = 9;
copy_a = a[0];
swap(a, a);
assertEquals("copy_a should be a[0]", copy_a, a[0]);
```

Apart from the above suggested test cases, you could also write test cases when either of a[] or b[] are null. Hope this helps.